# RDLC multiply values by 100 on live env

Tags: c#, azure, report, rdlc, syncfusion

I have some problem with RDLC report.

I am using Syncfusion Controls (Works great) for RDLC reports, and I noticed on my localhost everything Works fine. But when I deploy my code/app on live (MS Azure) it is multiplying currency boxes by 100.

Thanks,

Comment: That must be annoying. What's your question?

Comment: How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to occur, when the deployed application localization region in azure differ from your Local machine. So please share your machine and Azure deployed machine culture and also share the reproducible RDLC report to validate the currency textbox expressions for providing possible suggestions.